# How to deal with asynchronous completion handler to capture still images programmatically AND sequentially with AVFoundation

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

In the iOS app I am writing, I need to capture images automatically without user interaction.  Once the application starts, it sequentially needs to take a picture with the device camera, sends it to an external web service, wait for the web service response, then take a second image, sends it, wait response, takes a third picture, sends it... and so on.
So far I am using AVFoundation and `captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection`.

I am having a hard time to fit the asynchronous image capture with my 'sequential' algorithm. My `ViewController` has a `captureImage` that should update a property (`currentImage`) with captured image data:

```
-(void)captureImage {  
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = .... 
    // .... code here to get the connection, not relevant here .... //

    __block ViewController *weakSelf = self;

    [self.output captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
        completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
            weakSelf.currentImage = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:
                [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer]];

        NSLog(@"end of completion handler");         
    }];

    NSLog(@"end of captureImage");
}
```

Then I call `captureImage` from the method `doStuff` implementing my algorithm.  Note that `doStuff` is called from a button in the View to start the automated capture process.

```
-(void)doStuff {
    [self captureImage];
    if (self.currentImage == nil) { NSLog(@"NIL"); }
    .... send the currentImage to web service .... (not relevant here)
    // get second image after web service result is available
    [self captureImage];
    .... send the currentImage .... (not relevant here)
}
```

As you probably guess, the issue is that although the call to `captureImage` returns, the asynchronous call to the completion handler given to `captureStillImageAsynchronously` has not yet been performed.  Hence `self.currentImage` stays nil.  I noticed that the completion handler seems to run after `doStuff` finishes (my understanding of iOS application thread is still vague, but I guess that the main thread executes the completion handler code when it has no more of my code to execute... which is too late).

How should I implement such a sequential capture of images in my iOS app? My use case really requires to be able to control the sequencing without user interaction. I do not have a lot of experience with iOS development, so I guess I missed something important.  Any advice will be welcome!

Comment: I recommend you to use AFNetworking library which handles most of the stuff for you.

Comment: @casillas - thanks for pointing me to AFNetworking lib. My problem is related to the AVFoundation and asynchronous completion handler. Networking is ok so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, according to your description you have two asynchronous methods and you want them to be called sequentially in a loop.

You can approach this problem as follows:

First define these asynchronous methods:

```
typedef void (^completion_t)(id result, NSError* error);

- (void)captureImage:(completion_t)completion {
    // ...
}

- (void)uploadImage:(UIImage*)image params:(NSDictionary*)params completion:(completion_t)completion {
    // ...
}
```

Then define a private helper method `captureAndUpload` which basically sets up a continuation for method `captureImage` which calls `uploadImage`. The continuation of `uploadImage` tests whether it should repeat and if this turns out to be true calls `captureAndUpload` again:

```
- (void)captureAndUpload {
    [self captureImage:^(UIImage* image, NSError *error) {
        if (image != nil) {
            [self uploadImage:image params:someParams
                   completion:^(id result, NSError *error) {
                if (result != nil) {
                    if (repeat) {
                        [self captureAndUpload];
                    }
                    else {
                        // ..
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // ...
                }
            }];
        }
        else {
            // ...
        }
    }];
}
```

---

A more complete example which takes care of concurrency issues:

```
@interface Foo : NSObject

-(instancetype)init;

- (void) resume;
- (void) suspend;

@end


typedef void (^completion_t)(id result, NSError* error);

@implementation Foo {
    int _resumed;
    BOOL _running;
    dispatch_queue_t _sync_queue;
}

- (instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _resumed = 0;
        _running = NO;
        _sync_queue = dispatch_queue_create("imageuploader.sync_queue", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);

    }
    return self;
}

- (void) resume {
    dispatch_async(_sync_queue, ^{
        if (++_resumed == 1) {
            [self captureAndUpload];
        }
    });
}

- (void) suspend {
    dispatch_async(_sync_queue, ^{
        --_resumed;
    });
}


- (void)captureAndUpload {
    _running = YES;
    [self captureImage:^(UIImage* image, NSError *error) {
        if (image != nil) {
            [self uploadImage:image params:nil
                   completion:^(id result, NSError *error) {
                if (result != nil) {
                    if (_resumed > 0) {
                        dispatch_async(_sync_queue, ^{
                            [self captureAndUpload];
                        });
                    }
                    else {
                        dispatch_async(_sync_queue, ^{
                            _running = NO;
                        });
                    }
                }
                else {
                    // ...
                }
            }];
        }
        else {
            // ...
        }
    }];
}

- (void)captureImage:(completion_t)completion {
    // ...
}

- (void)uploadImage:(UIImage*)image params:(NSDictionary*)params completion:(completion_t)completion {
    // ...
}

@end
```

This example is still not complete, though: it does not handle errors, there's no way to cancel the underlying network request, and it's not clear what the state of the "uploader" (an instance of `Foo`) currently is. That is, we might want to know when the last upload has been completed after suspending the uploader.

Comment: This is clever and looks promising... I am going to implement this approach and will let you know. Thanks a lot for your proposal !

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to pass a block parameter to your captureImage method.

```
- (void)captureImage:(void(^)(NSData*))completion {
  AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = ....
  // .... code here to get the connection, not relevant here .... //

  __block ViewController *weakSelf = self;

  [self.output captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection
                                           completionHandler: ^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {
                                             NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithData:
                                                                      [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer]];
                                             completion(data);
                                             NSLog(@"end of completion handler");         
                                           }];

  NSLog(@"end of captureImage");
}
```

Then update your doStuff method:

```
-(void)doStuff {
  [self captureImage:^(NSData* data){
    // Do things with your data.
    [self captureImage:^(NSData *data){
      // Do things with the next data.
    }];
  }];
}
```

Now, if you'll be capturing many images, the nested block callbacks will get numerous (i.e., ugly).

But you could define the handler block as a local variable.

```
  void (^handler)(NSData*) = ^(NSData*data) {
    self.currentImage = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
    // Do things with your current image.
  };

  int maxImages = 42;
  for (int i = 0; i < maxImages; i++) {
    [self captureImage:handler];
  }
```

Furthermore, if you want to ensure that your images are uploaded in the sequence in which they were captured, you can take a look at the data passed back in the completionBlock of captureStillImageAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:, which includes an EXIF dictionary. The relevant value will be keyed as `kCGImagePropertyExifDateTimeOriginal`.